# Multi-methods with multi-parameters or one method with object parameter

Tags: c#, class, methods

Consider the following; I have a class with X and Y variables. the Idea of class is to change the position of points in both X axis and Y axis . I made a three methods in the first place for this purpose as :

- the first one is to chage to X position
- the second to change the Y position
- the third one is to change both X and Y by passing on object for this class

The Code as

```
    public class ChangePosition
{
    public int X_AxisPosition;
    public int Y_AxisPosition;

    public ChangePosition(int X_Axis,int Y_Axis)
    {
        this.X_AxisPosition = X_Axis;
        this.Y_AxisPosition = Y_Axis;
    }
    public void ChangeXAxisPosition(int XValue)
    {
        X_AxisPosition = XValue;
    }
    public void ChangeYAxisPosition(int YValue)
    {
        Y_AxisPosition = YValue;
    }
    public void ChangeXAxis_YAxisValues(ChangePosition NewLocaltion)
    {
        if (NewLocaltion == null)
        {
            X_AxisPosition = default;
            Y_AxisPosition = default;
            throw new NullReferenceException("Invalid Inputs");
        }
        ChangeXAxisPosition(NewLocaltion.X_AxisPosition);
    }

}
```

After a while i rethinking and said why do i have two method in above (For Only either Axles), I could have the last one by passing on object form this class and set the unneeded Axis to zero as the following block showing U

```
public class ChangePosition
{
    public int X_AxisPosition;
    public int Y_AxisPosition;
    public ChangePosition(int XValue, int YValue)
    {
        X_AxisPosition = XValue;
        Y_AxisPosition = YValue;
    }
    public void ChangeXAxis_YAxisValues(ChangePosition NewLocaltion)
    {
        if (NewLocaltion == null)
        {
          throw new NullReferenceException("Invalid Inputs");
        }
        X_AxisPosition =(NewLocaltion.X_AxisPosition);
        Y_AxisPosition =(NewLocaltion.Y_AxisPosition);
    }
}
```

Could someone told me in term of best practices which of the previous code block is better? and Why?

Comment: The code that suits your business needs is always better than the one which doesn't. Frankly, your question is not good for SO.

Comment: Such question should be migrated to [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As this is more a code review that a SO question. Here are some: You shouldn't use `NullReferenceException` on parameters, use `ArgumentNullException` instead. If the parameter is incorrect (`null`), don't reset the fields. Don't make fields public.But like @Ňuf said. it's a Code review item.

Comment: @J.vanLangen - thanks for your points, but note if I'm not set the fields to **default** this could case an issue in the value that I expected . For example consider i use one of the method that acting on only one axis (either `ChangeXAxisPosition` or `ChangeYAxisPosition` ) and then I used the last method (`ChangeXAxis_YAxisValues`) and the object that i passed is **null** then I expect zero value for both axis (as nothing happen), but this is not gona happen. The Axis will have the previous values of either one of the method above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice for such entities as "position" or "vector" is to make them *immutable* - because its *identity* depends only on its *state*. It means that two `ChangePosition` objects, initialized with same `X_AxisPosition` and `Y_AxisPosition` are *equal*. So, whenever you want to change a field of immutable enitity, you always can simply replace the whole object. The fact that two points with the same state may be considered as different entities in your code may lead you into troubles.

In your case, `public void ChangeXAxis_YAxisValues(ChangePosition NewLocaltion)` doesn't make sense, since whenever you could use it like

```
someObject.Position.ChangeXAxis_YAxisValues(new ChangePosition(x, y));
```

you should better write

```
someObject.Position = new ChangePosition(x, y);
```

A common practice for points/positions is to use `struct`, `struct` is actually mutable, but its identity is represented with its state (`struct`'s with same values of fields are equal, but not classes). It is also good to make its fields `readonly`, if it doesn't slow performance significantly.

So, keep it simple:

```
public struct ChangePosition
{
    public int X_AxisPosition;
    public int Y_AxisPosition;

    public ChangePosition(int X_Axis,int Y_Axis)
    {
        this.X_AxisPosition = X_Axis;
        this.Y_AxisPosition = Y_Axis;
    }
}
```

Also, normally you may find useful to implement `+` operator.